# Pull remote SVN and merge local changes

Tags: svn, git, wordpress, version-control, import

We use WordPress for development, but often make a lot of modifications. We're looking for a way to always keep our development version up to date with our modified version.

It possible to import all of the [WordPress SVN](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/) commits, branches and tags, but merge these with any we've made in our repo.

For example if we had removed the readme.txt file in our local repo, when we did another import from the WordPress SVN it would display the changes between this files and allow us to decide to to merge, update etc.

If not SVN is this possible with Git?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a vendor branch. We used it with wordpress and it works well.

[Subversion svn:externals file override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754459/subversion-svnexternals-file-override/3785904#3785904)

Comment: That sounds perfect, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can merge from the WordPress SVN repo into your local repo, but you need to keep track of what revisions you have merged, and you need to remind yourself to do the merge.

There is no concept of live forking in SVN. The closest you can get is [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html), but that does not allow you to check in local modifications.

Comment: Yep it's a shame I can't make changes to a folder under svn:externals otherwise that would be perfect.

In terms of doing the merge, is there any way to automate the process of getting all of the branches/tags etc from the remote repo or would I just export the external repo and check it into mine and figure out the merges?

Comment: Well, you can make changes and check them in if you have write permissions in the externals repo, but I understand that is not your case. To automate the process you need to take your favorite scripting language and the svn command line client and do some nice hacking.

Comment: Unfortunately SVN does not support this kind of live tracking. It must be tricky anyway to develop against such a moving target. If possible I would recommend you to write extensions rather than modifying existing code, but I understand that this is not possible in all cases.

Comment: It's not that tricky because releases are versioned and we develop against that version. I wondered if we could speed up getting a development version setup by pulling the latest WordPress version and merging it with out local modifications.